# GRPC Repeated field does not transcode to an array as body parameter in REST API

Tags: rest, google-cloud-platform, grpc, google-cloud-endpoints, proto

I´m having little luck trying to send a PUT request with JSON containing an array of objects to my GRPC Server using REST. Using GRPC however it accepts an array just like expected. This is what I have defined in my proto file:

```
message UpdateRequest {
    repeated Data data = 1;
    int32 Id = 2;
}

message UpdateResponse {
}

message Data {
    int32 id = 1;
    string name = 2;

}

rpc Update(UpdateRequest) returns (UpdateResponse) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
       put: "/v1/data/{Id}"
       body: "*"
     };
}
```

This deploys successfully to GCP Endpoints but according to the GCP enpointsportal the request body is supposed to only contain a single object like:

```
{
    "data": {
       
    }
}
```

instead of an array of objects like expected:

```
    {
    "data": [
       {},
       {}
    ]
}
```

I´ve tried with replacing the "*" in the body with "data"

```
    rpc Update(UpdateRequest) returns (UpdateResponse) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
       put: "/v1/data/{Id}"
       body: "data"
     };
}
```

This also compiles, but fails when trying to deploy to GCP endpoints with the following message:

kind: ERROR
message: "http: body field path 'data' must be a non-repeated message."

Any suggestions as to how I should go about solving this would be greatly appreciated.

Update:
Heres the contents of my .yaml file.

```yaml
type: google.api.Service
config_version: 3

name: xxx.xxx-xxx.dev

title: xxxx
apis:
  - name: x.x
  - name: x.y


backend:
  rules:
    - selector: "*"
      address: grpcs://xxx-xxx-app-xxxx-lz.a.run.app
```

Comment: can you share the content of your .yaml files? There may be an issue with your configuration which is prompting this error

Comment: I sure can @rsalinas, I´ve pasted the contentsa of the .yaml file used for this particular API in my original post. I´ve edited out all the specifics, such as the real names and URL´s but aside from that. This is all it contains. Thanks for helping me out with this one!

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue, according to GCP support.
Here is the google issuetracker link: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/178486575

Answer (score 0):

There seems that this is a bug in GCP endpoints portal. I´m now successfully sending update requests with arrays containing object through CURL and my frontend application, although this does not work through endpoints.